# Can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: java, windows, macos, compatibility

I have made a Java game that is a mix between Pacman and Snake.

It works fine on my computer. I have tried sending it to my friend, he has a Mac and I have a Windows. His computer says

> can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

How would I fix this? I have tried looking it up, but I can not find a fix. (If more information is needed let me know I will add it.)

Comment: http://www.iclarified.com/28180/how-to-open-applications-from-unidentified-developers-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion

have you tried googling your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell your friend to go to `System preferences > Security & privacy` and there you can allow 3rd party applications to be run. He will need to enter his password.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably the best option for most users, since it maintains some security:

1. Right-click (or control-click) the application in question and choose “Open”
2. Click the “Open” button at the next dialog warning to launch the app anyway

You can do this with any third party app that gives you this warning dialog and open it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

go to finder then application then Hold down the Control key and click the application icon. From the contextual menu choose Open.